# Access requests and invitations not showing up under Users and Permissions

Tags: sharepoint-online

I have an issue where myself (site collection administrator), and the site owners cannot see Access requests and invitations under the Users and Permissions section in Site Settings on a couple of sites.  It shows up there on some other sites for myself and the site owners of those sites.  As far as I can tell they are all team sites.

I know that you can get to it using the Site permissions link.

My question is what causes it to show up there?  I looked through my Site Features and they are the same for the sites that have it show up as the ones that don't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Head over to Site Settings > Site Permissions and look for "Access Request Settings" in the permissions bar. Click on it and make sure that "Allow access requests" are checked and that there is a valid email adress.

As soon as this is done, it should show up under Users and Permissions in site settings.

If it still doesn't show up, the reason might be that there never has been a single access request to the site. Use a account that does not have any access and create a access request, then it should show up.

Comment: It took an access request for the link to show up. Thanks!

Comment: Thought so. :) You are welcome

Comment: Once I created the first Access Request, the menu option appeared after that.  Even if there were no existing pending requests.

Answer (score 0):

This is true for Collection Adminstrators, but not always true for site owners with lesser rights.

We use a custom set of permission levels for our site owners (they are not given Full Control permissions, but they have more than Edit permissions). We haven't been able to determine the minimum set of permissions required to view and act on "Access requests and invitations" yet, so if you know what these are, please detail. Thanks, - tombraman

P.S. Our "Manage" permission level, which aims to limit site owners from creating new sites and security groups and change look/feel, consists of all SharePoint permission levels except for these:

- Manage Permissions  -  Create and change permission levels on the Web site and assign permissions to users and groups
- Create Subsites  -  Create subsites such as team sites, Meeting Workspace sites, and Document Workspace sites.
- Apply Themes and Borders  -  Apply a theme or borders to the entire Web site.
- Apply Style Sheets  -  Apply a style sheet (.CSS file) to the Web site.
- Create Groups  -  Create a group of users that can be used anywhere within the site collection.

Comment: Could you clarify your answer?